# Connecting to WCF Service on the same network

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have a WCF service deployed on IIS7.5 on windows 7. It is using basicHttpBinding since this service is to be consumed through a windows mobile 6.5 application.

If I try to connect from the same machine (192.168.0.201) everything works as it should. However if I try to connect from another machine on the same network, (here's the weird part) It manages to find the service however any successive calls fail.

If I browse to the service's wsdl page from a web browser it responds with "the page cannot be found", although the "you have created a service" page is found!

Note that browsing to wsdl page from the local machine works fine as well.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have MEX configured properly.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx

Comment: <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

should I add the <dns value = "..."> to it ?

Comment: Check the clocks on the two machines. If they are off by more than 5 minutes then WCF will start denying your requests. This is a security feature to prevents replay of messages. The time offset can be changed in the system.serviceModel section of the config. 5 Minutes is the default.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to it than just the endpoint.  Do you have a behavior?  It is all in the documentation.

[How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx)